# Refresh entire webpage but not applet

Tags: java, html, applet

On a webpage I open a Java applet into another independent window. I have to refresh the entire webpage where the applet is called. This has the effect to close and reopen the applet. I wish to let the applet and not refresh it. How could we do such a thing?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: You can use AJAX to refresh just the parts of your website that you want to change.

Comment: Use Ajax. You can take all the form parameters and perform a Ajax post. Libraries like Jquery JS, will help me make this call, without much coding effort. (also will shield you from browser quirks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AJAX to refresh the parts of the page you want to update.  This'll also probably make the reloading smoother and use up less bandwidth.

Comment: Yes it works with AJAX, I didn't know this technology, thanks.